# WPF Animation on listbox items

Tags: wpf, animation

Any idea what approach I would follow to get the items of a databound listbox to "fly" into the their position in the listbox similarly to the effect you see when a deck of cards is dealt in those Windows Card Games? (I'm using WPF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to extend the `Panel` class and use it as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of your `ListBox.ItemsPanel` property. It's really easy... there's just two methods to override; one to measure the items in the `ListBox` and one to arrange them. Here is a microsoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) on the subject.

Here is perhaps a [more useful article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control) [unfortunately, no longer available] that shows how to animate the items. For your effect, you would simply set the from value on your position animations to be the same location just off the viewable area for each of your items. For example, using a from position of `0, finalSize.Height` would mean that each item would slide to its position from the bottom left corner of the `ListBox`.
You could use your new animated `Panel` as follows:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <YourXmlNamespace:YourAnimatedPanel AnyCustomProperty="value" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you Sheridan!  I used the "more useful article" link as is and it provided the effect I had in mind.

Comment: Just a point to bear in mind for other users who come across this...I've noticed that the animation gets rather dogslow though when the listbox contains a couple hundred items and I resize the screen (by dragging the window border).  The animation is still fine when loading up the listbox though (and that's what I wanted) - it's just the resizing of the screen that causes my GUI to stu-stu-stutter!  But since my scenario does not involve the user constantly resizing the screen, I'll not worry about this one.

Comment: You can just apply the animations to newly added items, so when the user resizes the `Window`, the items will just 'jump' to their new positions... it won't look as nice, but it shouldn't stutter when updating. If you did want to do this, simply add a `private List` of type `UIElement` to your custom `Panel`. At the end of the `ArrangeOverride` method, clear your `List`, then add each child from the `Panel.Children` property into it. The next time the method is called, this `List` will contain the children that were previously in the `Panel`. Then animate items not contained in the `List`.

Comment: The link to the more useful article is broken.